# Boon JSON - Change Field Name for Object Deserialization

Tags: java, json, boon

I am using [Boon JSON](https://github.com/boonproject/boon/wiki/Boon-JSON-in-five-minutes) and I'd like to change the name of a field on a class that is being generated from JSON.

I just want to change

```
{"first_name": "Cristine", "last_name": "McVie"}
```

So it maps to the Java fields:

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

I've already got everything working (ie, if I use camel-case in the JSON, the object is created properly.

---

I've tried the `@JsonPropery` and (based on the suggestion in comments) the `@Named` annotations on the class, like so:

```
public class Person {
    @Named("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Named("first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    @Named("first_name")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
```

---

Just for edification, this is why I didn't see `@JsonProperty` working at first.  This app is running in Eclipse debug mode, and I was trusting Eclipse to redeploy the updated code, but adding an annotation is apparently NOT enough to trigger the update.  Had to restart the app to pick it up.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the fields with `@Named`? E.g. `@Named("first_name")`

Comment: Just tried it, thanks for suggestion.  Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add either a `SerializedName` annotation (like GSON) or a`JsonProperty` annotation (like Jackson) to the fields, like so:

```
import org.boon.json.annotations.JsonProperty;
import org.boon.json.annotations.SerializedName;

public static class Person {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    String lastName;
}
```

You can see another example [in the documentation](https://github.com/boonproject/boon/wiki/Boon-JSON-in-five-minutes#using-annotations-to-customize-serialization-property).

Comment: Hm, I had tried `@JsonProperty`, let me look at the some more. thanks.

Comment: OK, tried that again and it is working - thanks.  Thanks for directing me to the right spot in the docs, I couldn't seem to find it (and the TOC links seem to be off)